# What is the difference between googly and doosra spin?

Tags: cricket, terminology, technique, spin

I can see some of the spin bowlers bowl googly and some bowl doosra in international cricket matches.

What is the basic difference between googly and doosra spin?

How they differ from each other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A 'doosra' is a delivery that an off-spinner bowls with an off spin action that spins from right to left. (This is different to a normal off spin delivery that spins left to right.)

A 'googly' is a delivery that a leg spinner bowls with a leg spin action that spins from left to right. A 'googly' is also referred to as a 'wrong'un'. (This is different to a normal leg spin delivery that spins right to left.)

Saqlain Mushtaq was the inventor of the 'doosra' and he bowled it quite well. Currently, Muttiah Muralidaran, Harbhajan Singh and Ajantha Mendis bowl it very well. The master of the Doosra is definitely Muttiah Muralidaran.

Shane Warne and Anil Kumble are one of best 'wrong-un' bowler ever.

Comment: Good answer, the only inaccuracy is that Shane Warne didn't bowl many wrong-uns. His main variation delivery early in his career with 'the Flipper' that went straight on, low and fast off the pitch and later in his career he developed a 'slider' that was similar to the Flipper but was easier on his shoulder. Warne always has shoulder problems and the wrong-in strains the shoulder to bowl, hence he didn't bowl them often. Another example of a great wrong-un bowler is Brad Hogg who would often bowl more wrong-uns than regular leg breaks.

Comment: @Bogdanovist: Thanks for your comment and valuable information

Answer (score 0):

dossra is better than googly .When a batsmaen is a righthanded the doosra spins in the other direction and at confuses the batsmen .And the googly spins inside the righthanded batsmen the googly is a legspinner variations and the doosra is a off spinner variations .BUT but i am a offspinner

Answer (score -3):

Dusra delivery comes faster without spin where as googly spins a bit after meeting the pitch with a flighted delivery.